# Change the "flow" direction of a Spark TileLayout

Tags: layout, flex4, flex-spark

In a Flex Spark TileLayout, it seems you can easily change the order the elements with the `orientation` property, set either to `rows` or `columns`.  One will make the elements flow from top-to-bottom, left-to-right, and the other will make them flow from left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

However, I'm wanting to be able to arrange elements from bottom-to-top, right-to-left, as in the following (with two rows):

```
  6 4 2
7 5 3 1
```

or with three rows:

```
    6 3
  8 5 2
  7 4 1
```

Is it possible to do this with some combination of TileLayout's properties, or would I need to make a custom layout?

Comment: The TileLayout won't do this, you would need to make a custom layout or try some sort of hack by reversing the order of the elements in the dataProvider - but even that is not exactly what you're after as it won't give you that "empty" space that appears in the upper left of your diagrams.